# Tense of the statement

Tags: tense, subjunctives

What is the tense of this statement:

> If I had money, I would buy all the happiness in the world.

Comment: How about providing a context, and then asking your question?

Comment: Both of the answers are wrong. It is _subjunctive_. The part before the comma is _conditional_: the "had" is _not any particular tense_; it is the auxiliary used to form the conditional "if I Had". The part after the comma is the _subjunctive_ part; the "would" is _not any particular tense_; it is the appropriate auxiliary for subjunctive mood.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: Why do you say *had* is the auxiliary there? Isn't it just the verb 'to have' meaning 'to possess'?  *If I had had the money at the time, I would have bought that house.*  There, the first *had* is the auxiliary, and *have* in *have bought* is the auxiliary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tense](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm) is past but the time is present as we are talking about the present, now.

Answer (score 1):

> If I had money

Simple past tense of *have*.

> [then] I would buy all the happiness in the word.

Technically, I believe this is a present tense of *buy* with *would* as an auxillary verb, but that's not really important to the meaning of the sentence.

What is important is that this entire sentence follows the pattern of a [past-present mixed conditional](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/mixedconditional.html) expression.

Comment: Actually, *buy* is the plain form, not the present. It is an example of an infinitive :) Consider * *He would buy**s** all ...*, which is ungrammatical because of the present tense ending '-s'.